# Convert ps aux to json

Tags: json, linux, jq

I try to convert the output of `ps aux` into Json format without using Perl or Python! For these I have read about jq. But I have success to convert the commandline output into json.

How to convert a simpe `ps aux` to Json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ps aux | awk '
BEGIN { ORS = ""; print " [ "}
{ printf "%s{\"user\": \"%s\", \"pid\": \"%s\", \"cpu\": \"%s\"}",
      separator, $1, $2, $3
  separator = ", "
}
END { print " ] " }';
```

Just adjust columns which you need from ps aux output.

Comment: could I ask for some more help?

Answer (score 1):

`jq` can read non-JSON input. You'll want to pre-process the input with `awk` first:

```
ps aux |
  awk -v OFS=, '{print $1, $2}' | 
  jq -R 'split(",") | {user: .[0], pid: .[1]}'
```

If you want an array instead of a sequence of objects, pipe the output through `jq --slurp 'add'`. (I swear there's a way to do that without an extra call to `jq`, but it escapes me at the moment.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an only-jq solution based on tokenization.

Tokenization can be done using:

```
def tokens:
  def trim: sub("^ +";"") |  sub(" +$";"");
  trim | splits(" +");
```

For illustration and brevity, let's consider only the first 10 tokens:

```
[tokens] | .[0:9]
```

Invocation:

```
$ ps aux | jq -c -R  -f tokens.jq
```

Or as a one-liner, you could get away with:

```
$  ps aux | jq -cR '[splits(" +")] | .[0:9]'
```

First few lines of output:

```
["USER","PID","%CPU","%MEM","VSZ","RSS","TT","STAT","STARTED"]
["p","1595","55.9","0.4","2593756","32832","??","R","24Jan17"]
["p","12472","26.6","12.6","4951848","1058864","??","R","Sat01AM"]
["p","13239","10.9","1.5","4073756","128324","??","R","Sun12AM"]
["p","12482","7.8","1.2","3876628","101736","??","R","Sat01AM"]
["p","32039","7.7","1.4","4786968","118424","??","R","12Feb17"]
["_windowserver","425","7.6","0.8","3445536","65052","??","Ss","24Jan17"]
```

#### Using the headers as object keys

See e.g.
https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#convert-a-csv-file-with-headers-to-json

Answer (score 0):

I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/aberezin/a0cdec3c125851a96d4281183b6dd427) that to convert ps output to json.  It uses jq under the covers so you need to install that. But you do not need to know jq

Answer (score 0):

Dumps the fields specified by the -o flag as an array of PID objects:

```
ps ax -o "stat,euid,ruid,tty,tpgid,sess,pgrp,ppid,pid,wchan,sz,pcpu,command" \
    | jq -sRr ' sub("\n$";"") | split("\n") | ([.[0]|splits(" +")]) as $header | .[1:] | [.[] | [. as $x | range($header|length) | {"key": $header[.], "value": (if .==($header|length-1) then ([$x|splits(" +")][.:]|join(" ")|tojson|.[1:length-1]) else ([$x|splits(" +")][.]) end) } ] | from_entries]'
```

This builds an array of the header fields, maps an array of {key, value} objects per output object, and then uses the built-in from_entries filter to object-aggregate these into the outputs.